How do I increase the storage size in Windows Sandbox?
By default, Windows Sandbox runs with only 40GB Storage Space which really isn't a lot:

Is there a way for me to increase the storage size? I'd like to at least double it to 80GB.

Based on my research, it is not possible

While the specific topic of this question is different, the answer to this is the same as I made on your other question regarding Windows Sandbox.

This question is similar to: How to run multiple instances of Windows Sandbox at the same time?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@music2myear The answer to many, many questions on Stack Exchange sites is "it's not possible". The two questions OP has asked are quite different and it is not appropriate to close all questions with the same general answer as duplicates, especially as this one now has a (partial) answer quite unrelated to the other question.

@BobSammers OP's own answer to their question here mirrors my own, and my answer was far more than "it's not possible"; it was a clear list of what IS possible. While an answer a month later appears to offer a workaround, OP has not confirmed this has worked for them, now 2 months later. I don't close the questions, the community does. I have only SUGGESTED that my answer on their previous question was correct, and the community chose not to affirm that. That doesn't make my actions wrong, especially in light of OPs own admission.

I found a somewhat tedious workaround to increase the virtual disk size of the already running sandbox, and add an additional volume. But I couldn't increase the size of the system volume (C:) itself.
Prerequisites: Hyper-V installed on the host. The guide below uses the "Edit disk..." action of the Hyper-V manager.
Steps:

On the host machine:

Start the sandbox. Let it run in the background (that is, switch back to the host).

Locate the vhdx image for the sandbox. It should be under C:\Users\All Users\Microsoft\Windows\ContainerStorages\Sandboxes\<some-uuid-here>\sandbox.vhdx (or C:\Users\All Users\Microsoft\Windows\Containers\Sandboxes\<some-uuid-here>\sandbox.vhdx on older systems).
There may be multiple folders under Sandboxes, check the vhdx date to locate the current one.

Start Hyper-V manager as an administrator, and connect to the local computer (Action > Connect to Server... > Local Computer). It should automatically select the freshly connected machine.

Select Action > Edit Disk...

On the Locate Disk page, browse for the sandbox.vhdx from step 2 above.

Proceed to the Choose Action page, and select Expand

Proceed to the Configure Disk page, and increase the desired disk size from 40GB to whatever you like.

Proceed to the Summary page, and select Finish to commit your changes.



Now, switch to the sandbox for the steps below:

Run the Disk Management console, diskmgmt.msc.
Notice that the Disk 0 size has been increased, and there is unallocated space after volume C:.
Right-click on the unallocated space, and select New Simple Volume....
Go through the New Simple Volume wizard to create a volume.



Unfortunately, I couldn't find a way to extend the system volume, as a Virtual Disk Management error pops up complaining that "Bitlocker Drive Encryption cannot be used because critical Bitlocker system files are missing or corrupted".
Note that the volume created in step 12 can be mounted into an empty directory, so it might be good enough for large programs residing in a single directory on drive C:.
On a closing note, most of the host side steps could be automated (e.g. using the Resize-VHD cmdlet). And probably the sandbox-side could be as well.

After doing lots of research, I've concluded that as of 2024/08/31, you can not change the storage size in Windows Sandbox.
Other users are also discussing the same issue here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-sandbox-disk-space/b768bfcc-5eac-445e-88b3-196811161536
